# How to transform "dot" to "slash"?

Tags: db2

In a context of using SQL DB2:

The sql instruction 
`CHAR(MyDate, EUR)` transforms `25/12/16` into `25.12.2016` 
(and `CHAR(MyDate, ISO)` transforms `25/12/16` into `2016-12-25`)

Is it possible to get directly `25/12/2016` 
(or `2016/12/25`) 
without using the greedy scalar function
`TRANSLATE(CHAR(MyDate, EUR), '.', /')` 
(or `TRANSLATE(CHAR(MyDate, EUR)`, '-', /')

Maybe *General Settings* somewhere ...

Comment: You mean to change the default format that dates are presented? Would this help? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Comment: No, I know how to change defautl format date (/ , or - or . as separators)   it's the scalar function Char (Mydate, ISO), or char(mydate, EUR) that shows Dots, whatever your date format is. I want slash

Comment: So what do you want to do? Isn't `MyDate` a `date` column?

Comment: Like this? `select to_char(current date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') from sysibm.sysdummy2`

Answer (score 4):

`to_char(MyDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` is the correct answer
(or `to_char(MyDate, 'DD;MM;YYYY')` if you want ; instead of /)

Beware : MyDate must be a `timestamp` zone.

If MyDate is a `Date` Zone, you should code

`to_char(timestamp_iso(MyDate), 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

(or `to_char(timestamp_iso(MyDate), 'DD,MM,YYYY')` if you want , instead of /)

Answer (score 1):

DB2 returns dates according to the client application's localization settings.  If the client application is using the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, then DB2 will return dates in the standard format for the US (MM/DD/YYYY).

If you change your localization settings to something else (for example, `fr_FR.UTF-8`), you'll get dates back in that country's standard format (for France: DD.MM.YYYY).

On Linux/UNIX you can see your current localization using the `locale` command.  Note that DB2 uses `LC_CTYPE` to determine your locale.  As long as you have the locale available (i.e. check `locale -a`) you can just set the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable before starting your application:

```
$ locale | grep LC_CTYPE
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

$ db2 connect to sample

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.5
 SQL authorization ID   = USER1
 Local database alias   = SAMPLE

$ db2 values current date

1         
----------
09/26/2016

  1 record(s) selected.


$ db2 terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.

$ export LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8

$ db2 connect to sample

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.5
 SQL authorization ID   = USER1
 Local database alias   = SAMPLE

$ db2 values current date

1         
----------
26.09.2016

  1 record(s) selected.
```

On Windows, you can't change locale quite as easily, so you'll need change your regional settings.

Comment: Ok, but do you know the way to change local setting in a Iseries (= AS400) environment ? A kind of SQL order that would look like SET DATEFORMAT = '*EUR' (or so ...)